# Strange behaviour in GeometricTransformation

Tags: graphics3d, bugs, geometry, geometric-transform

**Bug introduced in 13.0**

**Bug is fixed in Version 13.1 **

---

I came across the following strange behaviour with the GeometricTransformation function.

```
rt1 = ReflectionTransform[{-1, 1, 0}];
rt1[{x, y, z}]
rt2 = ReflectionTransform[{0, 1, -1}];
rt2[{x, y, z}]
rt3 = ReflectionTransform[{1, 0, -1}];
rt3[{x, y, z}]
```

The output of this is as expected giving

```
{y, x, z}
{x, z, y}
{z, y, x}
```

respectively. These are just reflections in the planes x=y, y=z and x=z.

Now if I now do this for Graphics (I have a tetrahedron that I wish to show with its mirror image).

```
tetrahedron = Tetrahedron[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}];
tetrahedronmirrorxy = GeometricTransformation[tetrahedron, ReflectionTransform[{-1, 1, 0}]];
tetrahedronmirrorxz = GeometricTransformation[tetrahedron, ReflectionTransform[{1, 0, -1}]];
tetrahedronmirroryz = GeometricTransformation[tetrahedron, ReflectionTransform[{0, 1, -1}]];
GraphicsRow[{Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.1], tetrahedronmirrorxy, tetrahedron}], PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}],
Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.1], tetrahedronmirrorxz, tetrahedron}], PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}],
Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.1], tetrahedronmirroryz, tetrahedron}], PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]}]
```

This gives the following output:

[image: Plots of Tetrahedrons and mirror images]

Why are the tetrahedrons in the second two images stretched ?

I am using Mathematica 13.0 on Mac OS 12.3.1

Comment: I reproduce the bug with version 13.0.1 on Windows 10 x64, but not with version 12.3. So the bug is introduced in 13.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It must be a bug. If we replace `normal` from `{1, 0, -1}` to `{1, 0, -1} // N`,it work.Here we also draw the mirror plane `Hyperplane[normal, {0, 0, 0}`

```
tetrahedron = 
  Tetrahedron[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}];
normal = {1, 0, -1} // N;
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.1], 
   GeometricTransformation[tetrahedron, ReflectionTransform[normal]], 
   tetrahedron}, {Opacity[.8], Cyan, Hyperplane[normal, {0, 0, 0}]}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I will inform Wolfram Technical Support

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer from Technical Support.

"ReflectionTransform is not behaving properly" - Suggest that if the community agrees that this is posted as a bug.