# Bug in GeometricTransformation

Tags: graphics3d, geometric-transform

Is this bug in newer versions of Mathematica still present? Cube is deformed with rotation angle being odd multiply of `Pi/2`.

```
$Version
Table[Graphics3D[
   GeometricTransformation[Cube[], RotationTransform[n, {0, 1, 0}]], 
   PlotRange -> 1.2, PlotLabel -> n], {n, 
   Table[k Pi/2, {k, 0, 4}]}] // Row
```

---

[image]

Comment: [No](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KFrA.png).

Comment: @Domen I am always being unlucky with version.

Comment: Seems like these Transformation bugs were fixed in 13.1 (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267836/strange-behaviour-in-geometrictransformation?rq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Table[
  Graphics3D[
   GeometricTransformation[Cube[],
    RotationTransform[n, {0, 1, 0}]],
   PlotRange -> 1.2,
   PlotLabel -> n,
   SphericalRegion -> True],
  {n, Table[k  Pi/2, {k, 0, 4}]}] // Row
```

[image]

The cubes are not deformed; however, the different label sizes causes the size of the cubes to vary. Separate the labels:

```
Grid[
 Transpose@Table[
   {n, Graphics3D[
     GeometricTransformation[Cube[],
      RotationTransform[n, {0, 1, 0}]],
     PlotRange -> 1.2,
     ImageSize -> 100]},
   {n, Table[k  Pi/2, {k, 0, 4}]}],
 ItemSize -> {12, Automatic},
 Spacings -> {-6, 0}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Or more simply using [`Labeled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html)

```
Table[
  Labeled[
   Graphics3D[
    GeometricTransformation[Cube[],
     RotationTransform[n, {0, 1, 0}]],
    PlotRange -> 1.2], n, Top],
  {n, Table[k Pi/2, {k, 0, 4}]}] // Row
```

[image]